# Deriving the formula in binary independence model

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I probably should post this  to comsci/cstheory, but since the part I am stuck at is mostly about deriving the probability term, so I am posting this here.

Given

$$\begin{align}
query, \vec{q} & = \langle x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_t\rangle\\
document, \vec{x} & = \langle x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_t\rangle\\
\\
p_t & = P(x_t=1|R=1,\vec{q})\\
u_t & = P(x_t=1|R=0,\vec{q})\\
\end{align}$$

So I have this (is this called Naive Bayes conditional independence assumption?)

$$O(R|\vec{x}, \vec{q}) = O(R|\vec{q}) \cdot \prod\limits_{t:x_t=q_t=1} \frac{p_t}{u_t} \cdot \prod\limits_{t:x_t=0,q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}$$

and in the next step, it becomes this

> (quoted from [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/), by Christopher D. Manning, Prabhakar Raghavan and Hinrich Schütze)
>
> We can manipulate this expression by including the query terms found
>   in the document into the right product, but simultaneously dividing
>   through by them in the left product, so the value is unchanged. Then
>   we have:

$$O(R|\vec{x}, \vec{q}) = O(R|\vec{q}) \cdot \prod\limits_{t:x_t=q_t=1} \frac{p_t(1-u_t)}{u_t(1-p_t)} \cdot \prod\limits_{t:q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}$$

So the question is how do I transform the part from

$$\prod\limits_{t:x_t=0,q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}$$

to

$$\prod\limits_{t:q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t} \cdot X$$

and what is the $X$ so that it has to be divided in another term to maintain equality?

$$\prod\limits_{t:x_t=q_t=1} \frac{p_t(1-u_t)}{u_t(1-p_t)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $x_t$ can only get the values 0 and 1.

You have the expression:

$$\prod_{t: x_t=q_t=1}\frac{p_t}{u_t}\prod_{t:x_t=0,q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}$$

And you want to find out how is it transformed to

$$\prod_{t: x_t=q_t=1}\frac{p_t}{u_t}\frac{1-u_t}{1-p_t}\prod_{t:q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}.$$

The answer is quite simple. Take term

$$\prod_{x_t=q_t=1}\frac{1-u_t}{1-p_t}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}.$$

It is equal to 1. Split it into two parts:

$$\prod_{x_t=q_t=1}\frac{1-u_t}{1-p_t}\prod_{x_t=q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}.$$

Since it is equal to one, you can multiply the first expression by it without changing it:

\begin{align}
&\prod_{t: x_t=q_t=1}\frac{p_t}{u_t}\prod_{t:x_t=0,q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}=\\
&\prod_{t: x_t=q_t=1}\frac{p_t}{u_t}\prod_{t:x_t=0,q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}
\prod_{x_t=q_t=1}\frac{1-u_t}{1-p_t}\prod_{x_t=q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}=\\
&\prod_{t: x_t=q_t=1}\frac{p_t}{u_t}\prod_{x_t=q_t=1}\frac{1-u_t}{1-p_t}\prod_{t:x_t=0,q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}\prod_{x_t=q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}=\\
&\prod_{t: x_t=q_t=1}\frac{p_t}{u_t}\frac{1-u_t}{1-p_t}\prod_{t:q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}.
\end{align}

Here I used the following two properties of multiplication:

$$\prod_{i\in I}a_i\prod_{i\in I}b_i=\prod_{i\in I}a_ib_i,$$

and

$$\prod_{i\in I}a_i\prod_{i\in J}a_i=\prod_{i\in I\cup J}a_i,$$

where $I$ and $J$ are disjoint index sets and $a_i, b_i$ are objects which can be multiplied and multiplication is associative and commutative.

Comment: erm, how do u get the second part? how $\prod\limits_{x_t=0,q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}$ becomes $\prod\limits_{x_t=q_t=1}\frac{1-p_t}{1-u_t}$? yea, $x_t$ can be either 0 or 1

Comment: $x_t=0, q_t=1$ does not become $x_t=q_t,q=1$. They both become $q_t=1$.

Comment: thx for the prompt reply, still need some time to really get the idea.

Comment: Suppose there are only two indexes $t=1,2$, with $x_1=0, q_1=1$ and $x_2=1, q_1=1$. Then condition $q_t=1$ captures both indexes $1$ and $2$, since $x$ can be only zero and one.